# com.google.ads.AdView failed to instantiate?

Tags: android, admob

i am not able to add admob to my app.

i imported jar file to my project.

i added permissions and activity to my manifest.

```
enter code here
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.oodevs.treasurerapp"
       android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
       ..
    </activity>
```

`

XML Layout coding

```
enter code here
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@color/backgroung"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />
```

it gives me d following error "com.google.ads.AdView failed to instantiate"..

even when i run the project add view is not appearing..

Comment: have you look into this https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android

Comment: yes. i followed all the steps..  still the error remains.

Comment: have you put GoogleAdMobAdsSdk in libs folder or not...

Comment: yes i had put in lib folder..

Comment: have you done this.  
    // Create the adView
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

Comment: the problem solved. I was trying to load in android 2.3. Admob supports 4.0.3 only. So i had that error.